# Can you be a commercial pilot if you have a criminal record?

Tags: commercial-aviation, career, uk

Is it possible to become a pilot in the UK with a criminal record?

Comment: If you have minor stuff as "3 points on your driving licence", "1000 debt", "Parking ticket", etc. I don't think you will be much affected. But then again, sometimes the decision making is purely discretional. Just like a motorway cop can pull you over and have a serious chat with you, but not necessarily give you ticket. Obviously, if you have been banned as a DUI driver, chances are that you will be rejected

Comment: What kind of a commercial pilot do you want to be? Do you want to be a flight instructor? A pilot for an airline? Do you want to tow advertising banners?

Comment: @hagubear Are points on a driving license "minor" in this sense? "I was prosecuted for doing bad things while controlling a vehicle" sounds quite serious when you're applying for a job controlling a vehicle in an industry which is very keen on safety.

Answer (score 9):

[British Airways](http://www.britishairways.com/careers/futurepilot/fppFaqs.shtml) has this to say:

> If you have been cautioned, warned or convicted of a criminal offence (other than parking offences) we suggest you check whether you will be able to obtain an airside pass by visiting [www.dft.gov.uk](http://www.dft.gov.uk).
>
> In order to be employed as a pilot with British Airways you will be required to undergo a Criminal Record Check for every country in which you have been a resident, or worked in, for 6 months or more in the past 3 years.

Admittedly, [the DFT](http://www.dft.gov.uk)'s website is a maze of information, and it seems very difficult to find any information; I'd suggest giving them a call, to find out for your particular convictions.

[Airside Manager](http://www.airsidemanager.co.uk/Airside-Referencing.aspx) has some more detailed information on airside passes, in general.

Comment: wording seems to suggest it would depend on the actual crimes (type, number, and timeframe). A conviction for shoplifting is less likely to get your blocked from getting an airside pass than a conviction for drugs traficking I'd warrant to guess for example.

Comment: I thought responsibility for the security checks passed from the DfT to the CAA earlier this year?